# Rank function () to work as 1 or 0 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rank

I needed help with finding a way of doing the following in SQL Server.

Basically, in Excel, I can write something like:

```
IF(COUNTIF(A:A:A2) > 1:1:0))
```

What this Excel code does is that IF IT finds a customer number repeating in the customer number column, the formula returns 1 else 0.

I included this in my code

```
Select
    Contract_nr,
    Customer_number,
    Rank()OVER(ORDER BY customer_number) AS tester
    Productname,
    Sales_date
From 
    table namn
```

The `rank()` returns 1100, 1105 and so on...

How can I make IT so my tester column returns instead 1 or 0 IF a customer number repeats?

Comment: If you are trying to get distinct counts try "Select count(distinct customer_number) from tablename where..."

Comment: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. `LAG`/`LEAD` might help, but it depends on the database and version.

Comment: also look into the PARTITION keyword that will reset the number on a field. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: Interesting. How can this be solved in SQL server 2012?  The purrpose of adding this tester column to show IF a customer number is repeating is to see IF a customer bought more than one product. Usually I do this in excel. IT would be great to do this in SQL server 2012

Answer (score 2):

```
with cte as (
Select
    Contract_nr,
    Customer_number,
    case
       when count(*) over (partition by Customer_number) > 1 then 1
       else 0
    end as tester
    Productname,
    Sales_date
From 
    table namn
```

Comment: I didn't know you could use over with count!

Comment: Yep. You can use it with any aggregate or windowing function.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a self join.  Lead and Lag is a good option if you are SQL Server 2012 or above.  But this should work pretty well.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        Contract_nr,
        Customer_number,
        CASE WHEN t2.Contract_nr IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [CustomerNumIsRepeat],
        Productname,
        Sales_date
    FROM table as t1
    LEFT JOIN table as t2 ON t1.Customer_number = t2.Customer_Number AND t1.Contract_nr != t2.Contract_nr
```

Comment: Added a distinct to prevent repeating rows when there are more than one duplicate records per customer_number.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `WITH` clause to get the distinct count per customer number like so:

```
; With CustomerNumberCount AS
(
    SELECT Customer_number, COUNT(*) AS RecordCount
    FROM table
    GROUP BY Customer_number
)
SELECT t1.*
    , CASE WHEN t2.RecordCount > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [CustomerNumIsRepeat]
FROM table as t1
    LEFT JOIN CustomerNumberCount as t2 ON t1.Customer_number = t2.Customer_Number
```

This will ensure you only ever get 1 row from t1 (versus potentially getting the same row more than once if the customer number appears 2 or more times).